# make particular service logs to be written in separate file in syslog.conf

Tags: linux, logging, syslog

One of the service is writting logs by default in /var/log/messages file. I want that service logs to be written other file.

Logs in /var/log/messages files are being dislpalyed as below.

> Nov 20 16:18:40 testserver ServiceName:

I tried changing the configuration in /etc/syslog.conf as below

> cat /etc/syslog.conf
>
> *.info;authpriv.none;cron.none          /var/log/messages
>
> ServiceName                             /var/log/servicename.log

But still the logs are being written in /var/log/messages file only instead of /var/log/servicename.log.

Request to suggest how to get logs in to other file.

Best Wishes,
KJ.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for this command is:

```
ServiceName.* -/var/log/ServiceName.log
```

[Reference: Rsyslog outputting to custom log file](https://superuser.com/questions/626977/rsyslog-outputting-to-custom-log-file)